# Perforce and how to create symbolic links on samba share in Windows

Tags: windows, samba, symbolic-link, perforce

I am using Perforce and have Workspace of project under Linux. The project contains many symbolic links. I have no problems with Perforce and the symbolic links as long as I work on Linux. However, if I mount the project via Samba to my Windows computer and if I create a Workspace to this Samba share, then the symbolic links break down. It looks like Perforce cannot read and write the symbolic links on my Samba share correctly.

Is there solution or workaround to force Perforce to create Linux compatible symbolic links on a Samba share?

Comment: Which Windows version, and is Linux the server or the client?

Comment: I am using Windowx XP SP3. Linux is the client, ie. I access Linux from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not have native symlink support until Vista/7.

---

If you are connecting to a Windows share from Linux, try adding the `sfu` option to the `mount` command:

```
mount -t cifs -o sfu,(other options) //server/share /mountpoint
```

---

If you are running Perforce on Windows and connecting to a share on Linux, and your Windows version does not support symlinks, you cannot use them. (There's a slight chance Services for Unix can help, but I haven't used it much.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am working under Windows XP and access a Linux server via Samba. So, there seems no solution so far.

Comment: @stefan: In case of XP, my answer above applies: Windows XP does not have symlink support.